# Get Schengen visa from a US consulate, but fly in from India

Tags: india, schengen-visas, france, iceland, h1b-visas

I am an Indian citizen residing in the US on an H-1B visa. I am applying for a Schengen visa from the Spanish consulate in San Francisco to visit Spain, France, Germany, and Iceland this summer. However, I will first be visiting family in India and then directly flying into Europe.

Are there any issues with getting the Schengen visa issued in the US if I’m not traveling from the US to Europe directly?

Comment: Border Control will be interested as to whether you fulfill the entry conditions of the Schengen Area. When a visa is required, it must be valid upon **entry**. As far as the visa is concerned, the Border Control **doesn't care** where you are entering from.

Answer (score 4):

No.  The Schengen Visa Code requires visa applicants to apply in their place of residence.  There is no requirement to arrive in the Schengen area directly from your place of residence.

Your plan is not only permissible; it is the only plan allowed by the Schengen Visa Code.

(There is an exception for circumstances that make it impractical to apply in your place of residence, but it does not apply in this case.)

Comment: Didn't know about this. Is USA considered the place of residence for folks on an H1-B?

Comment: @hihello123 residence is a more flexible concept than people sometimes seem to think.  It may be defined differently for different purposes.  For a Schengen visa application, yes, the fact that you live and work in the US in H-1B status means that you are resident in the US (you might _also_ be able to claim residence in your home town in your country of origin; it is a bit of a gray area).  The consulates I'm familiar with would require you to include documents attesting to your H-1B status as part of your application.